# finding the highest scoring home team for EVERY SEASON

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql, greatest-n-per-group

Below is my hive query trying to find out the highest scoring home team for every season.

```
select t1.season , max(t1.TOTAL_Goals) as Highest_Score
  from
 (select season, home_team_id, sum(home_goals) TOTAL_Goals
    from game_kpark
   group by season, home_team_id
 ) as t1
 group by t1.season
```

The result of the code above is the table below

```
t1.season   highest_score

20122013    118
20132014    179
20142015    174
20152016    173
20162017    204
20172018    185
```

If I include `t1.home_team_id` after `SELECT` and `GROUP BY` at the end,
it returns all team's added-up score for every season, not the highest score.

How do I correctly write a query to see the corresponding team of the highest score for every season?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `rank()` analytic function:

```
select s.season, s.home_team_id, s.TOTAL_Goals
from
(
select s.season, s.home_team_id, s.TOTAL_Goals, 
       rank() over(partition by season order by s.TOTAL_Goals desc) as rnk
  from
 (--team season totals
  select season, home_team_id, sum(home_goals) TOTAL_Goals 
    from game_kpark
   group by season, home_team_id
 ) s
) s
where rnk=1; --filter teams with highest rank per season
```

Comment: Works just fine. Thank you so much! @leftjoin